# Comparison between strings and integers in matlab

Tags: string, matlab

I am doing some classification and needed to convert an integer code to strings for that reason. I wrote something like this:

```
s(1).class = 1;
s(2).class = 7;
s(3).class = 9;

[s([find([s.class] == 1)]).class] = deal('c1'); %first conversion
[s([find([s.class] > 1)]).class] = deal('c2'); %second conversion
```

and was surprised to find s being a 1x4 struct array after the second conversion instead of the expected 1x3 struct array with the values. 
Now, after some research, I understand that after the first conversion the value of `s(1).class` is `'c1'` and the argument to `find` in the second conversion is not what I assumed it would be. The `[s.class]` statement actually returns something like the string `'c1\a\t'` with ASCII escape sequences for bell and horizontal tab.

As the comparison does work (returning the matrix `[1 1 1 1]` and thus expanding my structure) I assume that matlab converts either the operand `[s.class]` or the operand `1`. 
Which is it? What actually is compared here numbers or characters?

And on the other hand is there a built in way to make `>` more restrictive, i. e. to require the operands to be of the same type and if not to throw an error?

Comment: Perhaps it will be easier if you explain what you want to achieve. Even better, post example input and desired output

Comment: It is not so much a matter of wanting to achieve something. I am just curious to what goes on when I tell matlab `'a' > 1`, as I ask above which operand is converted. If it needs to boil down to achieving something the second question is the relevant one: I would like to change the behaviour of `>` so that `'a' > 1` would give me some output like: invalid comparison between char and int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do the comparison `'ab' > 1`, the `char` array `'ab'` gets converted to a `double` array, namely the ASCII codes of the characters. So `'ab' > 1` is equivalent to `double('ab') > 1`, which gives `[1 1]`.

To get the behaviour you want (issue an error if one of the arguments is `char`) you could define a function:

```
function z = greaterthan(x,y)
if ischar(x) || ischar(y)
    error('Invalid comparison: one of the input arguments is of type char')
else
    z = x>y;
end
```

so that

```
>> greaterthan([0 1 2], 1)
ans =
     0     0     1

>> greaterthan('ab', 1)
??? Error using ==> greaterthan at 3
Invalid comparison between char and int
```

Comment: Why not simply use `ischar` – or `isnumeric` to check for numeric values?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you maybe know where I can find the specifics, I did not find them in the docs.

Comment: @ben_za In general, any arithmetic operation applied on strings treats the characters as if they were their numeric (ASCII) codes. As for where to find it, [this](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strings.html) is the only thing I've found (I didn't search much, though). It says: _The string is actually a vector that contains the numeric codes for the characters (codes 0 to 127 are ASCII)_.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have not provided any expected output yet, I am going with the observations.

You are using a comprehension method (by invoking `find`) to determine which locations you will be populating for struct `s` with the results from your method `deal` (takes the argument `c1` and `c2`).  You have already set your type for s{whatever).class in the first snippet you provided. Which means it is number you are comparing, not character.

There is this `isa` function to see which class your variable belongs to. Use that to see what it is you are actually putting in (should say int32 for your case).

Comment: I understand my output. Yes before the first population all the values of `s` are numbers. After the first population the value in `s(1)` is `'c1'`, which is a string of characters and as I write above the result of `[s.class]` after the first population is `'c1\a\t'`. I know that. The question is not what types I've got the question is what matlab _does_ with those types. Sorry if this was not clear from my question.